# How to keep the reference to a file/dir after renaming?

Tags: path, filesystems, file-rename

XCode 7.3 can detect if a project directory has been moved/renamed: not only it keeps the project in the "recent projects" dialog which appears at startup, but it also shows the new filename correctly and in the same position.

How can an application achieve this behaviour?

Is it feasible to store a reference to the inode instead of the file path? Are there other ways to know if a file gets moved/renamed?